# High memory consumption after migrating to jdk 17 from jdk 8

Tags: java, memory-leaks, tomcat9, java-17

I recently migration an application from jdk-8 + tomcat 7 to jdk-17 + tomcat 9. After migration I see application is using around 7 GB of memory which was earlier around 5 - 5.5 GB.
Heap size is not increasing its max 3 GB. I already analysed JFR, JVM native memory, GC logs but no luck.
Any suggestion where/what should I be looking at/for to find the cause of it?
Thanks !

Comment: Any specific reason why you chose Tomcat 9 over Tomcat 10? Nevertheless, check if [this](https://community.bmc.com/s/question/0D53n00007aEPHzCAO/tomcat-reaching-the-high-memory-utilization-fp-1219) can be of any use for further analysis.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.